# How to change request_uri in nginx proxy_pass?

Tags: sockets, mod-rewrite, nginx, url-rewriting, gunicorn

I am running a django application through gunicorn via unix socket and I have my nginx configuration which looks like this :

**Current NGINX config File :**

```
upstream django_app_server {
  server unix:/django/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server{
    listen 80;
    server_name demo.mysite.com;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://django_app_server;
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

so my django is running on a unix socket here , lets say if it was running on localhost then it has a url which looks like :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/demo/app1
http://127.0.0.1:8000/demo/notifications
```

**Main goal**

so what i want to do is , when someone visit http://demo.mysite.com/app1 they can access via proxy pass the url : http://127.0.0.1:8000/demo/app1

It would have been really easy if i would be running django on localhost tcp port and i could have easy done this and it would have worked for me :

```
server{
    listen 80;
    server_name demo.mysite.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/demo/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

}
```

How do i achieve this with my current nginx configurtion ?

Comment: This configuration *proxy_pass http:// django_app_server/demo/;* looks valid regardless of the upstream connection (TCP or UNIX domain socket). What can you see in the logs in that case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach is to use `rewrite ... break`, for example:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri @proxy;
}
location @proxy {
    rewrite ^ /demo$uri break;

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://django_app_server;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.