# Nginx rewrite request path with upstreams

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have a couple of upstreams that I should balance requests to.
The problem is that I need to rewrite url differently for each upstream before proxying the request.

So for example, I have request to `/ini/tial/path`. If request will be sent to upstream1, it should be transformed to `upstream1.nowhere:1111/u1/ini/tial/path`, if request will be sent to upstream2, it should be transformed to `upstream2:2222/u2/ini/tial/path`

Can this be achieved in nginx? I've found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36222000/how-to-change-request-uri-in-nginx-proxy-pass) however it rewrites the url first and then proxies the request, which makes it use the same (rewritten) url for all upstream servers. In my case rewrite rule depends on actual upstream server.

Answer (score 0):

Different ports are definitely not a problem, but difference in path seems to be a bummer.

Backends are defined in Nginx as

```
upstream backend_name {
  server 1.1.1.1:1111;
  server 2.2.2.2:2222;
}
```

and the corresponding proxying directive looks like `proxy_pass http://backend_name/path`. Note, the name of backend is referred by name, not as a variable. Generally `proxy_pass` is quite flexible and lets using variables inside, but there is no way to determine which server is chosen during request processing. (it **is** possible afterwards, at the time of logging – [`$upstream_addr varaible`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#variables))